# Meaning of center of mass : triangle

Tags: calculus, physics

Consider a triangle ABC, where $A=(x_1,y_1), B=(x_2,y_2)$ and $C=(x_3,y_3).$ Then it is well known that the centroid is $(\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3}, \frac{y_1+y_2+y_3}{3}).$

Why is the following sentence true?

> Centroid of a triangle is the point at which the triangle could be perfectly balanced on the tip of a pin.

I know the definition and properties of the centroid of triangle, but I couldn’t understand the sentence exactly.

For the definition and properties of it, see https://www.mathwarehouse.com/geometry/triangles/triangle-concurrency-points/centroid-of-triangle.php#ixzz66i8NwJ3q

My another question is

> In general, is the centroid of polygon ( for example, rectangle, pentagon, etc) unique?

Would you give me a hint or reference for it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The center of gravity is the point at which it can be balanced on the tip of a pin. This comes straight out of computing the Center of Mass of a triangle by taking a linear element and varying it through the height of the triangle using integration and the definition of the center of mass.

Comment: This question is more suitable for https://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You know _a_ definition and _some_ of the properties of a centroid, but we don't know which ones. It might be useful to actually say exactly which facts you know.

Comment: @DavidK I posted the definition and properties of it.

Comment: So you have already seen the term "center of gravity" applied to the centroid. In general, if you can touch a rigid object's center of gravity with the tip of a pin, you can balance the object on the tip of the pin when it is touching that point from underneath.

Comment: @DavidK I know the term “center of gravity.” However, I don’t know why the centroid is the center of gravity. Is it from the definition and properties of the centroid or other calculation?

Comment: Ah, I thought when you explained what you understood by linking to a page that said the centroid was the center of gravity, it meant you knew the centroid was the center of gravity. Next time maybe your own words would be better than a link. For this question, though, you seem to have some progress in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\vec{r_0} = (x_0, y_0, z_0)$ be the point on which the polygon could be balanced. The torque $d\vec{M}$ of an infinitesimal part of a polygon at coordinates $\vec{r} = (x,y,z)$ of mass $dm$ w.r.t the point $\vec{r_0}$ is given by
$$d\vec{M} = (\vec{r} - \vec{r_0})\times \vec{g}\,dm$$

The total torque $\vec{M}$ w.r.t. the point $\vec{r_0}$ is $0$ by definition of $\vec{r_0}$ so
\begin{align}
0 &= \vec{M} \\
&= \int_{\text{polygon}} d\vec{M} \\
&= \int_{\text{polygon}}(\vec{r} - \vec{r_0})\times \vec{g}\,dm \\
&= \left(\int_{\text{polygon}}(\vec{r} - \vec{r_0})\,dm\right) \times \vec{g}
\end{align}

And hence $\int_{\text{polygon}}(\vec{r} - \vec{r_0})\,dm$ is parallel to $\vec{g}$. The integral $\int_{\text{polygon}}(\vec{r} - \vec{r_0})\,dm$ is a vector always orthogonal to $\vec{g}$ so

\begin{align}
0 &= \int_{\text{polygon}}(\vec{r} - \vec{r_0})\,dm \\
&= \int_{\text{polygon}}\vec{r}\,dm - \int_{\text{polygon}}\vec{r_0}\,dm\\
&= \int_{\text{polygon}}\vec{r}\,dm - \vec{r_0}\int_{\text{polygon}}dm\\
&= \int_{\text{polygon}}\vec{r}\,dm - m\vec{r_0}
\end{align}
where $m$ is the mass of the triangle.

We conclude
$$\vec{r_0} = \frac1m \int_{\text{polygon}} \vec{r}\,dm$$
which is precisely the definition of the centroid.

Coordinate-wise, this means
$$(x_0, y_0, z_0) = \left(\int_{\text{polygon}} x\,dm, \int_{\text{polygon}} y\,dm, \int_{\text{polygon}} z\,dm\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is $\vec{g}$?

Comment: @04170706 $\vec{g}$ is the constant gravitational acceleration around Earth's surface. It is pointing downwards, and is of magnitude around $9.81 \text{m}/\text{s}^2$.

Comment: Thanks! You wrote “ the integral on polygon is a vector always orthogonal to $\vec{g}$.” Why is it true?

Comment: @04170706 Yes, the vector $\vec{r} - \vec{r_0}$ is the vector pointing from $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ to $(x,y,z)$, i.e. it is always in the plane of the polygon. The integral sums those vectors and we obtain another vector in the plane of the polygon, which is horizontal and hence orthogonal to $\vec{g}$.

Comment: @04170706 Also, perhaps it is unclear, the $z$ coordinate in the above calculation is always constant since the polygon is positioned horizontally.

Answer (score 3):

Is this a definition of [centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid) or has the centroid been defined and this is being stated as a property?  If you try to balance something on top of a pin the pin cannot exert any torque on the object.  The torque due to gravity around the pin must be zero.  Try cutting a shape (it doesn't have to be a triangle) out of cardboard and balancing it on your finger.

We can consider the torque around the horizontal $x$ axis.  If the density per area is constant over the shape, the torque around the $x$ axis is $\int y \ dA$ because a small area $dA$ will have a downward force proportional to $dA$ and will exert a torque of $y\ dA$.  The $x$ axis will pass through the centroid when this integral is zero.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems that your explanation is that I try to find, but I don’t understand it exactly. Would you give more explanation or reference for it?

Answer (score 2):

> Centroid of a triangle is the point at which the triangle could be perfectly balanced on the tip of a pin.

[image]

Here you are!

In mathematics and physics, the centroid (or *geometric center*) of a plane figure is the arithmetic mean (***"average"***) position of *all the points* in the shape.  The geometric centroid of a triangle is therefore also its **center of mass**, meaning that we could imagine all the mass of the plane object concentrated in this single point. For each point outside the centroid that has a certain little weight ($dW$) there is another point or more that balance this weight. Thus, the triangle is in equilibrium: there are no torques (you can think of the torque as the tendency of a force, here the weight, to rotate the body onto which it acts). If there wasn't such a balance around the centroid, the triangle would incline from one side and fall down.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What is the reason for that?

Comment: @04170706 Edited the answer for this

Comment: How can I know if the centroid is the arithmetic mean position of all points in the shape?

Comment: Well, this is a definition: the centroid or geometric center of a plane figure is the arithmetic mean position of all the points in the figure. For the triangle it is therefore also its center of mass and it happens to be the point where the three medians of the triangle meet